# Expected Decleration On UIButton SetUp

Tags: ios, swift

It keeps telling me there is an Expected decleration when i try to set up my button.

Here is the code:

```
    class MenuScene: SKScene {
var menuView = UIView()
let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
btn.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
btn.addTarget(self, action: "clickMe:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.menuview.addSubview(btn)
func clickMe(sender:UIButton!)
{
    let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as! GameScene
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    view!.presentScene(scene)
}
```

}

error is here: `btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

Please help,

Thanks!

Comment: This can't be all the code. Please edit your question and add the entire function. Also, Xcode tells you the line number of the error. Please indicate that as well.

Comment: ok ill put it in @ryantxr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is the code:

The problem is not the code, but where the code is. It is floating in space. You can't do that. Executable code like this can only go in one place: in the body of a function. You need to *put* the code somewhere. It can't float loose in your class declaration the way you have it.

Comment: its in a class: class MenuScene: SKScene {
    var menuView = UIView()
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    btn.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "clickMe:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.menuview.addSubview(btn)
}

Comment: Well, same answer. That isn't the body of a function. It's all just sitting there in spac, at the top level of your class declaration. You can't do that. That's what I said.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the answer by @matt, code has to be in a func. It's can't just be in the class like that.

```
class MenuScene: SKScene {
    var menuView = UIView()
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton

    func someFunc() {
        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        btn.setTitle("Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: "clickMe:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.menuview.addSubview(btn)
    }
    func clickMe(sender:UIButton!)
    {
        let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as! GameScene
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
        view!.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```